# Why would the name of a political party be a question? How common is this?

Tags: parties

[Wikipedia tells me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_owns_the_state%3F)

> Who owns the state? or Whom does the country belong to? (Latvian: Kam pieder valsts?) is a populist, anti-establishment party in Latvia.

Party names that are wordy/long and a question seem unnatural and weird to me. I would guess a short catchphrase is much more marketable.

Why would the name of a political party be in the form of a question? How common is this?

Comment: Not common; I don't know any other examples. Also it looks like the official name is just  KPV.LV, i.e. an abbreviation. https://kampiedervalsts.com/kontakti/

Comment: It is a rhetorical question. Whether you think using a rhetorical question for a party name is odd is mostly opinion.  It's pretty rare